# SSCE - Multiple-Step OLE DB operation generated errors

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce, oledb

I'm using a SQL Server Compact database (3.5).  I have run through every article on this site (and others) I could find about this issue, but can't seem to find the problem.  I am using Visual Studio 2012, VB.Net.

My provider string is:

```
Dim sqlConn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.SQLServer.CE.OLEDB.3.5;Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\pw.sdf" & ";Password=XXXyyy1234;Persist Security Info=True;")
```

My code where it all breaks down is:

```
'Create SQL Query
    Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT * FROM EmailGroups"

    'Create Dataset, Open Connection
    Dim dsPWC As New DataSet()
    Dim OleDbDataAdapter1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLString, sqlConn)
    sqlConn.Open()
```

And, of course, it breaks down on .Open().

I picked selecting from that datatable because it is a simple one.

EmailGroup_UID [int][PK]
EmailGroup_Name [nvarchar][length=50]

I'm sure I've been simply staring at this too long and can't see the forest for the trees anymore, so I'm hoping someone can slap me straight :)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  This code all works when tying to the original MS Access 2007 database (accdb). Different provider, of course.  And - I didn't import the tables, I re-created manually.

2nd EDIT:  Immediate Window says 'A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll'

Comment: Could you try to remove the Password and Persist Security info from that connection string?

Comment: I had already removed Persist.  I also started this whole thing off forgetting to put in the password and it 'barked' at me - telling me I need a password: 'The specified password does not match the database password'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use SqlCeConnection instead of OldDbConnection.

if you **must** use OleDbConnection, use "ssce:database password" like so:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.SQLServer.CE.OLEDB.3.5;Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\pw.sdf" & ";SSCE:Database Password=XXXyyy1234;Persist Security Info=True;"
```